# JWT Authentication and Swagger with .NET Core 3.0

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, .net-core-3.0

I am developing some Web API with .NET Core 3.0 and want to integrate it with SwashBuckle.Swagger.
It is working fine, but when I add JWT authentication, it does not work as I expect.
To do that, I added the code below:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Web API", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });
    });
```

After adding `AddSecurityDefinition` function, I can see the Authorize button and when I click it, I see the form below:
[image]

Then I type `Bearer WhatEverApiKeyIsfgdgdgdg845734987fgdhgiher635kjh`. After doing it, I expect to see `authorization: Bearer WhatEverApiKeyIsfgdgdgdg845734987fgdhgiher635kjh` in the request's header when I send a request to the Web API from Swagger, but authorization is not added to the request header. I am using SwashBuckle.Swagger(5.0.0-rc3). Please note there are many samples which work fine on .NET Core 2.0, but Swashbuckle swagger functions has changed on the latest version so I cannot use those samples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorization for JWT bearer in Swashbuckle .NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985240/authorization-for-jwt-bearer-in-swashbuckle-net-core-2)

Comment: On the link you mentioned there is no answer. Also .net core 3.0 is slightly different.

Comment: The answer is to add `.AddSecurityRequirement` (globally) or `.Security` (on the operation level) - as explained in the answers to the linked question. `AddSecurityDefinition` alone is not enough.

Comment: I added but nothing changed. I think that's why it is not selected as answer.

Comment: I answered this recently on another question have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872872/3952573

Answer (score 148, accepted):

After some research, I eventually found the answer [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/696)

Before seeing this page, I knew that I should use `AddSecurityRequirement` after `AddSecurityDefinition` because of many samples, but it was a problem that the function parameters have changed on .NET Core 3.0.

By the way, the final answer is as below:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { 
    Title = "My API", 
    Version = "v1" 
  });
  c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
    In = ParameterLocation.Header, 
    Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
    Name = "Authorization",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey 
  });
  c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
   { 
     new OpenApiSecurityScheme 
     { 
       Reference = new OpenApiReference 
       { 
         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
         Id = "Bearer" 
       } 
      },
      new string[] { } 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked.. Tip : don't forget to write "Bearer " before the actual token. And it's a bit annoying that swagger always says authorized, no matter what you write in the Textbox... Thanks!

Comment: Code presented here does not need to type Bearer before token:
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/jwt-authorization-token-swagger-open-api-asp-net-core-3-0/

Comment: Without `c.swaggerDoc(..)`, it works like charm on .NET core 5.0/6.0 with swashbuckle! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too. But need to add "Bearer" + JWT Token to that text box

Answer (score 37):

If you are using Swagger 3.0 then it has build-in support for JWT authentication.

You need to use ParameterLocation.Header,  SecuritySchemeType.Http, bearer, and JWT in OpenApiSecurityScheme as shown below.

After this, you **wouldn't need to specify token in Bearer {token} format**. Only specify the token and the security scheme will automatically apply it in the header.

```cs
// Bearer token authentication
OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Name = "Bearer",
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = "bearer",
    Description = "Specify the authorization token.",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
};
c.AddSecurityDefinition("jwt_auth", securityDefinition);

// Make sure swagger UI requires a Bearer token specified
OpenApiSecurityScheme securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Reference = new OpenApiReference()
    {
        Id = "jwt_auth",
        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
    }
};
OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {securityScheme, new string[] { }},
};
c.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! After many posts that did not work for me, this method did!!

Answer (score 23):

In the accepted answer, "Bearer " is required to be written before the actual token.
A similar approach in which typing **"Bearer " can be skipped** is the following:

```cs
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Example API", Version = "v1" });

c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "bearer",
    Description = "Please insert JWT token into field"
});

c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        },
        new string[] { }
    }
});
```

Here, only pasting the JWT token is required for this to work.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution updated for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.3.2, integrated with IdentityServer4, with an API secured using a Bearer token.

In `ConfigureServices()` method:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", SecuritySchemes.BearerScheme(Configuration));
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        { SecuritySchemes.OAuthScheme, new List<string>() }
    });
});
```

In `Configure()` method:

```cs
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/My.Api/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            options.OAuthClientId(Clients.TestClient);
            options.OAuthAppName("My Api - Swagger");
            options.OAuthClientSecret(Configuration["TestClientSecret"]);
        });

internal static class SecuritySchemes
{
    public static OpenApiSecurityScheme BearerScheme(IConfiguration config) => new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Description = "Standard authorisation using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        OpenIdConnectUrl = new System.Uri($"{config["TokenServerUrl"]}.well-known/openid-configuration"),
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Password = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new System.Uri($"{config["TokenServerUrl"]}connect/authorize"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { Scopes.Api, "My Api" }
                    },
                TokenUrl = new System.Uri($"{config["TokenServerUrl"]}connect/token")
            }
        }
    };

    public static OpenApiSecurityScheme OAuthScheme => new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
            Id = "Bearer"
        },
        Scheme = "oauth2",
        Name = "Bearer",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,

    };
}
```

Comment: This is a life saver. It also works for implicit flow where I changed Password to Implicit in the Flows setup. Thank you so very much!

Comment: OK, this is the only example that worked for me. I can't believe how difficult they make this.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to add a token manually and you want the scopes to be selectable along with passing a clientId to the identity server you can add something like this.

I have used implicit flow, but you can configure any flow using the following mechanism:

```cs
options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
  Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
  {
    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
    {                            
      AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("http://localhost"),
      TokenUrl = new Uri("http://localhost"),
      Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        { "Foundation API", "FoundationApi" }
      }
    }
  },
  In = ParameterLocation.Header,                    
  Name = "Authorization",
  Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2                    
});
```

The output will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is using NSwag and has landed here after searching the solution, here is the link from the official documentation.

[NSwag Enable JWT authentication](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCore-Middleware#enable-jwt-authentication)

PS: *I know the original question was for SwashBuckle, but Google shows this link first when searching for NSwag as well.*

Answer (score 0):

In Accept answer you have to manually  append "bearer" with token, this will create new issues, Swagger can append "bearer" with token watch this following link

[JWT Authentication and Swagger with .NET Core 3 and 5 YouTube video](https://youtu.be/nmwUfjtkaTM)