# How to use swagger to set the global JWT in asp.net core？

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, token

I have relearned asp.net core, and in my personal project, I used swagger interface documentation. I follow this documentation and it works fine, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.1. But I have a doubt, that is how to use the token, I am using the asp.net core 3.1 version. As shown in my picture, although it is not done by asp.net core, how can it be implemented in .net core?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL4Uw.png)

When I access an interface, I need a login token because I don't have permission. Can I use the global token in asp.net core?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179180/jwt-authentication-and-swagger-with-net-core-3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate a token by logging in, and then pass in this token to access some permission API, right?

You can refer to this code：

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
            {   
                      ////Name the security scheme
                config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat="JWT"
                });

                config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,

           //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
                Id = "Bearer"
            }

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

Code to generate token:

```
appsettings.json:

 "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "testUser",
    "Audience": "user",
    "Key": "this is my custom Secret key for authnetication"
  },

 private string GerarTokenJWT()
        {
            var issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: issuer, audience: audience,
expires: expiry, signingCredentials: credentials);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return stringToken;
        }
```

Login to generate token:

[image]

Then verify:

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. By the way, how will you store and manage the generated token?