# Adding authorization support in Swagger ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, swagger

I have a task to include authorization (JWT Bearer Token) in Swagger. There is a service where you can get the JWT Token, which is located on another server. And with this token in the header, you can send requests. I can not find examples and documentation, what I found most for Asp.net core. Any help by the way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization for JWT bearer in Swashbuckle .NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985240/authorization-for-jwt-bearer-in-swashbuckle-net-core-2)

Comment: I need for . net framework

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?